# Jenkins load statistic graph - master executors are missing

Tags: jenkins

I have set up Jenkins with a master node with 4 executors, and one additional slave node, also 4 executors.

When I look at the load statistics graph for the entire Jenkins (`https://<JENKINS-URL>/load-statistics`), then I see the 4 executors of the slave node. I verified this by changing the number of executors to 3 on the master and 5 on the slave - the load statistics graph went from 4 to 5.

When I go to the individual master node specifically and go to the load statistics graph there (`https://<JENKINS-URL>/computer/(master)/load-statistics`), then I do see the executors of the master node.

I found an issue in the Jenkins bug tracker that exactly describes my problem, but it appears to be abandoned: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32689

How do I get a load statistics graph of the entire Jenkins installation that includes the executors of the master node?